# getView in ListView Android stopped working and shows only first data

Tags: java, android, listview

I made some changes in some files (not the ones I am having the problem - or I think so) and suddendly my ListView stopped working. The problems is that, athough the data passed as an argument are correcct, the ListView generates only the 0 position.

However, I cannot unerstand why. Here is my code:

```
public BussinessAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BussinessListClass> listData) {
        this.listbussiness = listData;

        System.out.println("Business Adapter : Result :"+listData.toString());
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
        imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageloader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

    }   

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("Total number is:"+listbussiness.size());
        return listbussiness.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listbussiness.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Called at position :" + position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bussinesslist, null);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleNearby);           
            holder.imageView = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImageNearby);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        BussinessListClass item = (BussinessListClass) listbussiness.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

        if (holder.imageView != null) {

            holder.imageView.setTag(item.getPhoto() + item.getName());
            imageloader.displayImage(item.getPhoto(), holder.imageView, options, animateFirstListener);


        }
return convertView;
    }
```

The weird thing is this:

- Data are being printed out correctly
- in the getCount I do see 4, which is the size of the ArrayList
- but the getView gets called only for position 0.

Can anyone help me on that? it used to work last weeek :/

SOLUTION: problem was in xml, my height beame something like 10 times more, so I thought there was only 1 item but it was because I had to scroll and scroll to see the others.

Comment: use git bisect to find the faulty commit, or even the faulty line, then fix it or post it if you don't understand why it causes this issue.

Comment: have u changed the size of listview, are u able to scroll it and see more items

Comment: I can't see differences in the code - and the weird thing is that If I download my app from the market it plays normally. I want help in debugging it.

Comment: @PulkitSethi Yes that's it! Make it an answer and I will accept it - I just need to scroll almost to the bottomm to see data, it must be something in the xml that changes my listview height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have u changed the size of listview, are u able to scroll it and see more items. It probably is calling only for one position and it can only show that at any time